# An embarrassing error appears in a .bat file and not in CMD

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, escaping, wmi-query

I'm actually working on a "Computer Info Dumper" and I need to get the ram name + capacity, the problem is that the line that make this: it works in CMD, but not in a .bat file.

Here is the 'command': `powershell -command "GWmi CIM_PhysicalMemory|%{\"\"+ ([int]$_.banklabel.Replace('BANK ','') + 1) + \") \" + ($_.capacity/1GB)+\"GB from \"+($_.manufacturer)}"`

In CMD, it gives me the wanted result:

> ```
> 8GB from Corsair
> 4GB from Kingston
> 8GB from Corsair
> 4GB from Kingston
> ```

But in a .bat file, it gives me this error: (it will be translated because it's in French so the translation won't be perfect)

`To character Line:1 : 25`

`+ ... sicalMemory|{""+ ([int]$_.banklabel.Replace('BANK ','') + 1) + ") " + ...`

`Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.`

`+ CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException`

`+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline`

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: Why are you running this from CMD and not directly from PowerShell? And, if having a `.bat` is needed for some reason I cannot understand, why not call from you batch file to `powershell.exe -File "path/to/script.ps1"` or encode the expression to base64 and call `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand 'b64encodedstring'` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon it's a entire code, not only for ram, it's for all the info of the computer, and i don't wan't external file / code, everything in my file ^^

Comment: The question to why not encode all to base64 still stands and the question to why not run this directly with powershell still stands.

Comment: for the base64: i wan't the code to be readable because i think that i gonna put it on my github, and for the powershell part, i wan't it to be in batch, it's all, i'm too bad in powershell to make a entire program in it :D

Comment: Your code is PowerShell code tho, and having escaped PowerShell code in your batch file is not "readable"

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon if i give you the entire code, i will be more understandable i think

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon https://pastebin.com/raw/MWdJ5Ctu

Comment: This can be translated to PowerShell very easily, I can show you how it looks

Comment: what can be translated ?? it's already in powershell x)

Comment: All batch code from your pastebin I meant

Comment: @Dazd-PKZ, just escape the special character, `%` becomes `%%` in a batch file!

Comment: @Compo thanks you ! make an answer if you want me to +rep you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer:

In a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) the `%` character has a special meaning, so a literal character would require escaping. The escape character for a percent is another, i.e. `%%`.

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-CimInstance CIM_PhysicalMemory | %% { \"\" + ([Int]$_.BankLabel.Replace('BANK ','') + 1) + \") \" + ($_.Capacity / 1GB) + \"GiB from \" + ($_.Manufacturer) }"
```

Or preferably, don't use the `%` alias for `ForEach-Object` in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), and then you can match your Command Prompt code withn your script.

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-CimInstance CIM_PhysicalMemory | ForEach-Object { \"\" + ([Int]$_.BankLabel.Replace('BANK ','') + 1) + \") \" + ($_.Capacity / 1GB) + \"GiB from \" + ($_.Manufacturer) }"
```

You will see that I have more correctly allocated the `Capacity` units as `GiB`, and that I have replaced your `GWmi` alias for `Get-WmiObject`, with the recommended PowerShell v3.0+ alternative `Get-CimInstance`, *(alias `gcim`)*.